# List of events generated in Airflow

Tags: logging, events, airflow

I have searched online extensively for a list of events generated by Airflow logging but cannot find anything. There is plenty of info on how to configure logging but nothing about the event types generated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Airflow, there is an audit log that is kept, you can access it through the UI in the following path `Browse ->  Audit Logs`, or on the endpoint `<YOUR_AIRFLOW_URI>/log/list/`.

These events are also kept inside the metadata DB, in the `log` table.

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the update. I have seen the aspects of the UI that you refer to. I need a list of event types generated in order to confirm audit compliance. For example a list of event codes and description like Microsoft provide on their site. I need to understand what gets audited so I know what to alert on. Thank you